# Moving JTable rows downwards when new row is added to the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to maintain list of events generated by the user in a `JTable`.The `JTable` consists of 2 columns *Time* and *event* and 5 rows. When 1st event is generated it's data must be placed in 1st row of `JTable`, when 2nd event is generated the data in 1st row must be moved to 2nd row and the data of 2nd event must be place in the 1st row of the `JTabel` and so on up to 5th row. There is no limit to the events(n events can be generated). But i have to display only 5 events in `JTable` and older once will be stored in text file. I have tried some logics but they are failed to work.

This is my problem. Can any one give me an idea how to move rows downwards...

Regards...
Upendra.S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply add your new row at index 0 in your `TableModel`. If your `TableModel` extends from `DefaultTableModel`, you can even use the available [`insertRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#insertRow%28int,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.

For the requirement to only show 5 rows, you simple [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow%28int%29) the extra row from your `TableModel`.

Consult the [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information

Comment: thanks a lot.I didn't even think about adding new row at index 0. I am  placing new row at i'th position where i will be incremented for each event. No I got solution. Thank u.

Answer (score 3):

- have look at [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- part [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- method from [DefaultTableModel insertRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#insertRow%28int,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)